# How is the web crypto library encrypting a large files fast?

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I noticed that the `web crypto` library can encrypt via `ACM-GCM` `1GB` files relatively fast (for example, I can encrypt a `1GB` file in 10 seconds).
I know that streaming `ACM-GCM` throws the authentication out the door. My question is how is JavaScript encrypting the file so fast?

In `C#`. I have to load the entire file into memory to encrypt or decrypt it.

Is there something I'm missing?
Is it streaming the file?

Comment: Web Crypto API encryption methods ([`SubtleCrypto.encrypt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt)) require the plaintext to be an ArrayBuffer or typed array, which means that streaming is not possible.

Comment: @jfd348 So does it buffer the large file and encrypt with the same nonce and key?

Comment: Question asking why some piece of code acts in a certain way, such as running unexpectedly fast, really do need to include the code in question.